# Git merge upstream without losing changes

Tags: git, github

I am confused on the steps to take with the following case.

Let's say I have forked a repo and cloned it locally. Now, that I want to contribute to the upstream repo, I have created a local branch named, let's say, `newFeature`.

I've been working on this branch for a while and have a bunch of commits and now I am ready to push it, but I have realized that the main (upstream) is no longer at the same stage as mine.

What I need:

1. pull the upstream/main
2. merge it to my local branch `newFeature`
3. **DON'T** lose any of my changes... on the merge (some merge conflicts may be done, that's ok), but after I merge those changes how can I apply all my edits on top of it?

To sum up:
I need to update my local branch to be at the same level as the upstream/main and then reapply my changes on top of that; commit it all and *push*, so I can create a Pull Request.

I've read a lot of similar cases around but I am so confused that I don't think I now the right steps.

Comment: 3 is predicated on the false idea that the merge from upstream will somehow "overwrite" your changes. You can either merge or rebase but in any case your changes will be kept, or at least create conflicts *you* will be able to solve however you want. This is the very purpose of collaborative version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *apply all edits on top of it* (upstream), you are looking for a **rebase** rather than a merge.

You can do:

```sh
# Be on the feature branch
git checkout newfeature

# Retrieve the upstream changes
git fetch upstream

# Replay your commits on top of upstream/main
git rebase upstream/main
```

You might have some conflicts to resolve when rebasing.

Comment: ohh... never thought it would be that simple to do. Thank you sir :)